# Better way to convert an List<MyDataType> to List<String>

Tags: java

I am wondering if there isn't a better way to convert whole `Lists` or `Collections` as the way I show in the following code example:

```
public static List<String> getAllNames(List<Account> allAccounts) {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(allAccounts.size());
        for (Account account : allAccounts) {
            names.add(account.getName());
        }
        return names;
    }
```

Every time I produce a `method` like this, I start thinking, isn't there a better way? My first thought would be to create maybe a solution with some `generics` and `reflections`, but this seems maybe a bit over sized and maybe a bit to slow when it comes to performance?

Comment: Well, this is the best you can get IMO.

Comment: this is probably the "best way", but I would tweak it a little, `List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(allAccounts.size())`.

Comment: Until Java gets functional, your approach is fine.

Comment: Note that this is not "casting", but "converting". The word "cast" has a specific meaning which is not applicable here.

Comment: @Jesper: I think you are right, I changed it in my post

Comment: @mre: Yes that's a good idea. I also added this to my code above, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), there is a more functional approach:

```
return FluentIterable.from(allAccounts).transform(new Function<Account,String>(){
    public String apply(Account account){return account.getName();}
}).toImmutableList()
```

But that essentially does the same thing, of course.

BTW: the difference between this answer and RNJ's is that in my case the list will be created once, while in the other answer it's a live view. Both versions are valid, but for different scenarios.

Comment: +1 @SeanPatrickFloyd for returning immutable list - I think this is a better way now I look at it

Comment: Thank you for the Tip on Guava, I never had a look at it, but I will have a deeper look at it.

Comment: @RNJ no, not always. in some scenarios a live view is more appropriate

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at Google's [Guava](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html) library

Something like this should do it

```
final List<String> names = Lists.transform(myObjs, new Function<MyObject, String>() {
    public String apply(final MyObject input) {
        return input.getName();
    }
});
```

Comment: I didnt know there was a Lists class, I thought you had to use `Iterables`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I actually have exactly this kind of method in my personal library.

```
public static <TSource,TTarget> List<TTarget> castList(List<TSource> sourceList)
{
    List<TTarget> targetList = new ArrayList<TTarget>(sourceList.size());
    for (TSource t : sourceList) {
        //This will throw a ClassCastException if the types are not compatible
        //Be carefull
        targetList.add((TTarget)t);
    }
    return targetList;
}
```

Usage is very simple because the compiler infers the type for TTarget.

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
objects.add("One");
objects.add("Two");

List<String> strings = castList(objects);
```

Regarding the performance:
I think using generics is no problem here. But the need to copy the whole array is another story.

Comment: That is pretty close to what I was thinking about. I maybe would also add a String with the attribute name I want to fetch into the new List<String>. However I think you will get an cast exception if you would add to not castable types. Maybe you should add something like this to the `method header`?

Comment: You are right, you will get a ClassCastException if the types are not compatible. I will add a warning to the method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way. Casting is a difficult and dangerous thing. In your example, your are not able to cast a String to a MyDataType or vice versa, aren't you?
You might create an own List-Implementation with some kind of toStringList()-Method if you need these more often.

Comment: even if MyDataType extended String, he would not be able to cast a `List<MyDataType>` to a `List<String>`...

Comment: @assylias but he could still cast to `List<? extends String>` (which is kinda pointless, I admit.

Comment: @assylias: this was just an example to show the difficulties of casting

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way but it is not type safe

```
List<A> a = new ArrayList<A>();
List<B> b = (List)a;
```

but then you have to override the implementation of toString() method of your class to return the getName() value.
But there's no type checking,

And as mentioned you can of course do instead a loop and call getName on every object

Comment: Do you realise `List<B>` won't be a list of `B`'s if you do this?

Comment: Try this with `List<Dog>` and `List<Cat>`.

Comment: yes I do realize that but it answers the OP question, doesn't it? and as I mentioned it is not type a type safe approach

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `Iterables` and `Function` classes from the Guava libraries. You can create a new type of an `Iterable` using,

```
Iterable<String> newTypeIterable = Iterables.transform(oldTypeIterable, new Function<MyDataType, String> () {
   @Override
   public String apply(MyDataType from)
   {
     return from.getName();
   }
});
```

Turns out you can do this with the `Lists` class too!

Comment: No you can't change the type of a list in Guava, but you can easily create a different list from an existing one